# How to create an array of squared values of another array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I need to make a method `square_array` that takes in one argument which is going to be an array. This method needs to loop through the original array and multiply each element with itself then insert the squared value into the new array.

I'm getting an error when doing this `array[i] ** 2 = output[i]` I think it's because of the equals sign but I'm not sure.

```
def square_array(array)
  i = 0
  array = ('1'..'3').to_a
  output = []
  while i < array.length do
    array[i] ** 2 = output[i]
    i += 1
  end
end
```

I expect

```
square_array([1,2,3])
```

to return

```
[1,4,9]
```

Comment: "I believe I'm getting an error but I'm not sure" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Why are you setting `array` inside your function when it has been passed in to you as an argument???

Comment: Also, have you considered using [map](https://ruby-doc.com/core-2.6.1/Array.html#method-i-map)?  You can wrap it in a function if you want, but it's just as easy to simply write `output = array.map { |x| x * x }`.

Comment: My guess is that he's just starting out and doesn't really have the basics down, hence the `array[i] ** 2 = output[i]` and the overwriting of the original input in the method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When trying to declare a variable or assign a new value to it, it should be on the left side of the equals operator. So if you have `a` which is 5 and you want to assign the value of `a` multiplied by 2 to a new variable `b` you would do:

```
b = a * 2
```

and not

```
a * 2 = b
```

That's why `array[i] ** 2 = output[i]` isn't producing the result you expect it to produce.

Looking at your method, a few other things are a bit off:

```
def square_array(array)
  i = 0
  array = ('1'..'3').to_a
  output = []
  while i < array.length do
    array[i] ** 2 = output[i]
    i += 1
  end
end
```

You accept the `array` variable as an input, then you overwrite it by doing `array = ('1'..'3').to_a` (no need to use the single quotes `'` when declaring numbers (Integers)) and lose the input value. Usually you'd declare the array outside the method and then pass the value to the method. Something like this:

```
array = (1..3).to_a 
def square_array(array)
  i = 0
  output = []
  while i < array.length do
    output[i] = array[i] ** 2 #like explained in the first part
    i += 1
  end
end
```

But the method still doesn't return anything, so simply adding `output` as the last line in the method should solve the problem (remember, Ruby returns the last line of the method even without the `return` statement).
So something like this:

```
def square_array(array)
  i = 0
  output = []
  while i < array.length do
    output[i] = array[i] ** 2
    i += 1
  end
  output
end
```

I should also add, there's an easier way to write this method, using the `#map` function (like @pjs said) for example:

```
def square_array(array)
  array.map{|x| x**2}
end
```

You can then call the method by doing

`square_array(array)`

Comment: array.map{|x| x**2}
nuf said ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I'm still very new to this and what you've said is very insightful.

Answer (score -1):

Here, your assignment is mistake,

```
   array[i] ** 2 = output[i]
```

It should be

```
   output[i] = array[i] ** 2
```

Comment: That fixes one mistake, but still doesn't fix the function.